# psycopg2 copy_to interprets float value as string during insert

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a pandas dataframe which looks something like this when printing info `print(df.info())`

[image: Pandas DF Schema]

Now, I'm trying to insert this into a table in postgres using psycopg2's `copy_to` function. It looks something like this

```
def copy(conn, table, df):
    sio = StringIO()
    
    # Handle NaN
    # Since to_csv writes NaN as empty string, it causes trouble with copy_to since NaN is present in Numeric types
    # So converting NaN in Numeric types to -1
    df = set_empty_defaults_df(df)
        
    sio.write(df.to_csv(index=None, header=None, sep="|"))
    sio.seek(0)
    
    print("Table %s" % (table))
        
    with conn.cursor() as c:    
        c.copy_from(
            file=sio,
            table=table,
            sep="|"
        )
        conn.commit()
```

When I run this, I get the error `DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "0.0"
CONTEXT:  COPY time, line 1, column hour: "0.0"

[image: Error Image]`

It's very odd that psycopg2 is interpreting a double 0.0 as a string instead of a decimal value which it should be as pandas has the correct data type.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks like the data read from `StringIO` is not reinterpreted as float. Are you sure this is not the source of the problem?

Comment: Well CSV is a text format so I'm not sure what you where expecting? `psycopg2` is just dealing with what it is given. If you want more then, as @AlexF suggests, you have to do the interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "as a string" bit is a red herring — those quotation marks are probably just there to delimit the value. You real issue is that you are trying to store a value with decimals in an integer column.

For example, try the following at the `psql` prompt. You will get the same error message:

```
db=> create temporary table t (x integer) ;
CREATE TABLE
db=> \copy t(x) from stdin
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself, or an EOF signal.
>> 1.0
>> \.
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "1.0"
CONTEXT:  COPY t, line 1, column x: "1.0"
```

So you need to get pandas to print those columns without decimals, perhaps by converting them to integers, or by using some fancy formatting option of `to_csv` (I don't remember off the top of my head what there is).

Comment: The quotes are there as part of the error message, see [Message quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/55189.1633618509@sss.pgh.pa.us). If the data had been `Decimal` it would have worked: `select '0.0'::numeric::integer; 0`, so eliminating decimals is not strictly necessary.

Comment: I should have added that using `Decimal/numeric` will result in rounding:`select '1.4'::numeric::integer; 1 select '1.6'::numeric::integer; 2`.